# apply recyclerView adapter on multiple layout files-android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

at this point i have created a android project,
where, after clicking on a item from navigation menu>> one activity should open.

and that activity contains a recyclerview.
but what i want to do is, 
i have 2 more layouts 
1)introduction_layout.xml (contains>> 1 textview in cardview)
2)implementation_layout.xml (contains>> 2 textviews in cardview)

and, in that activity, i have implemented a bottom navigation view
as,

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

which contains 2 menu,
1)introduction
2)implementation

so i want is, when user will click on introduction, the activity should load introduction_layout.xml in recycler view
and when user will click on implementation, the activity should load, implementation_layout.xml.

here, i have some basic idea that i have to use viewtype in recycler adapter.
also i google for it.but nothing helped me to achieve desired output.

please anyone help me,
currently i have a recycler adapter for only one layout file.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter1.ViewHolder> {



    private String[] titles = {"Item one details",
            "Item two details", "Item three details",
            "Item four details", "Item file details",
            "Item six details", "Item seven details",
            "Item eight details"};



    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public TextView itemTitle;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.introText);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.introduction_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

but how can i create adapter for second layout file.
and how to call that adapter to set on recycler view?
because, i am updating layouts on menu item click
means after clicking on particular menu, the desired layout file should open...

here are some more information about my project:
1)my recycler view is in between nestedscrolview
as,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            .....
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

i managed the desired layouts to be open on button click like this,

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.b1)
        {

            NestedScrollView scroll = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
            scroll.removeAllViews();
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.introduction_layout, null);
            scroll.addView(view);
}
else if(id==R.id.b2)
{....}
else if(id==R.id.b3)
{....}
```

Comment: are you talking about two different recyclerviews?

Comment: No. recyclerView is the same. but let say, i want to update the layout in recyclerView dynamically(on button click)

Comment: so you want to update the same recyclerview with new xml on button click?

Comment: You should create two recyclerview for that in separate fragment

Comment: check this demo https://github.com/segunfamisa/bottom-navigation-demo

Comment: @shinil M S- yes exactly on button click the same recyclerview should update the xml layout

Comment: @pratik popat- thax for reference but what about recyclerview. i want to use it because i am displaying data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with *view types*.

`RecyclerView.Adapter` supports the notion of different view types, so that the items in your list can have different views.

First you need two different view holder classes.  I am assuming the intro text is the same on both views, so the implementation view holder can extend the introduction view holder.  If they are very different, they can both extend an abstract base view holder class.

```
    static class IntroductionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView itemTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.introText);
        }

    }

    static class ImplementationViewHolder extends IntroductionViewHolder {

        public TextView implText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            implText= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.implText);
        }

    }
```

You will need to override `getItemViewType`.  This is how you tell the adapter which view holder to use for which position.  If you are changing all the views at once, then your adapter can just have a current view type field:

```
        public static final int INTRODUCTION_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

        public static final int IMPLEMENTATION_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

        private int currentViewType;
```

Then use this to switch view holders:

```
        @Override
        int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return currentViewType;
        }
```

You'll need a way to change this:

```
        void setCurrentViewType(int currentViewType) {
            this.currentViewType = currentViewType;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Now you can call this adapter method when the user clicks on the `BottomNavigationView`.

Then your `onCreateViewHolder` override looks like this:

```
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

            switch (viewType) {
            case INTRODUCTION_VIEW_TYPE:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.introduction_layout, viewGroup, false);
                IntroductionViewHolder viewHolder = new IntroductionViewHolder(v);
                return viewHolder;
            case IMPLEMENTATION_VIEW_TYPE:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.implementation_layout, viewGroup, false);
                ImplementationViewHolder viewHolder = new ImplementationViewHolder(v);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
            switch (viewType) {
            case INTRODUCTION_VIEW_TYPE:
                IntroductionViewHolder introductionViewHolder =
                        (IntroductionViewHolder) viewHolder;
                introductionViewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[position]);
                break;
            case IMPLEMENTATION_VIEW_TYPE:
                ImplementationViewHolder implementationViewHolder =
                        (ImplementationViewHolder) viewHolder;
                implementationViewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[position]);
                // or do whatever else you need to do for implementation view
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, i am going to try this code. hope it will work in my case. but i have one more question. in my implementation layout there are 2 textviews. and i have totla 3 String[] one for introductionlayout text , and other 2 for implenetationlayout texts.namely, 1)intro[]        2)title[]      3)content[]    so what changes should i make in onBindViewHolder?

Comment: and also my another question is, as i have 2 layouts which i am dynamically showing on button click(one at a time). so how can i set the adapter on recyclerview? because in onclick of menu item, i have managed to inflate layout.you can see my updated question. in which i added the menuitem onclick listener.

Comment: will you please tell me why setCurrentViewType() is written?

Comment: to set the viewType from outside the adapter class.

Comment: yes, i can understand that. but anyone please tell me, how can i set adapater on recyclerview in the block of onclick.

Comment: yes.finally got the output...after resolving some mistakes.thanx @kris larson